# Filter and hide images with jquery regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a little problem, I want to hide some of feched images. Like gravatar and small images. Can someone give me an example of regex function?
How to hide images like this:

```
<ul id="grid"><li><img id="photo" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id%3D9698b3c319a46d14567b271cabcc85f1%26amp%3Brating%3DX%26amp%3Bsize%3D80%26amp%3Bdefault%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.setupswarm.com%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fravatar%2Fcache%2F9698b3c319a46d145.png"></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, there is no need for regular expressions:

```
$('img[src^="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php"]').hide()
```

(using the [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)). For more complex queries use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with a function as argument. In this function try to figure out, if the image should be hidden or not:

```
$('img').filter(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('href').search(/http:\/\/www\.gravatar\.com/) > -1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I tried this example, but its not working. I don't know why. Maybe there is need for extra library of jquery?